# React App: Map within HashRouter is having issues iterating the component

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-router

I am attemting to run a map similar to this:

```
const array=[
{

    componentName: 'ComponentOne'
},
{
    componentName: 'ComponentTwo'
},
]

<Switch>

  {array.map((object, index) => (
     <Route exact path='/correctPath'
     render={()=><object.componentName
     />}/>))}

</Switch>
```

The error I get is improper casing, the targeting of the property is correct. The error also shows that the component is correctly cased, even though it doesn't think it is. If I change all instances of the parameter 'object' to 'Object', I continue to get an error, even though the error shows the component in proper PascalCase. Thoughts?

Comment: What about pascal casing both `Object.ComponentName`? Also `Object` refers to the build in js object so that might also be causing you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to construct a properly cased react component, i.e. PascalCased. Also, don't use variable names (in any casing) of reserved javascript key words, like `Object`.

The more common pattern is to store a reference to the component in the array.

```
const array= [
  { component: ComponentOne },
  { component: ComponentTwo },
];

...

<Switch>
  {array.map(({ component: Component }, index) => {
    // Uses object destructuring to get and rename the component to Component
    return (
      <Route
        exact
        path="/correctPath"
        render={() => <Component />}
      />
    );
  })}
</Switch>
```